# Bulk Append File Names with numbers with cmd

Tags: windows, cmd

How can I batch append a directory of files using the window cmd so that they change from.

"file1"
"file2"
"file3"

to

"001 file1"
"002 file2"
"003 file3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to PowerShell instead of batch, you could do this as a one-off:

```powershell
gci |% { ren $_ (('{0:d3} ' -f $i++) + $_.Name) }
```

Which is more fully written as:

```powershell
$counter = 0
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { 
    $prefix = '{0:d3}' -f $counter++
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$prefix $($_.Name)"
}
```